# vim substitute text with some other portion on the same line in vim

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a text I need to change:

```
<tag name="aaaa" value="${bbbb}"/>
<tag name="cccc" value="${dddd}"/>
```

I need to get it to the form

```
<tag name="bbbb" value="${bbbb}"/>
<tag name="dddd" value="${dddd}"/>
```

that is, use the portion inside `${...}` of `value` to replace that inside `name`.

Comment: I want to use a macro, but not sure where to start with. thank you.

Comment: unless you have to do this operation thousands of times, I won't resort to macros but try using vertical editing instead.

Comment: why vertical editing would help (if you meant vertical editing as region editing)? aaaa may not be 4-character long. In the above, that was simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a macro use `qa` `q`.  Then use `@a` to execute the macro.

`qa` binds the macro to `a` then you can start typing to record the macro. Then pressing `q` again stops recording the macro.

So for your situation I went into command mode and typed:

```
qaf{lyf}2F"PxF"l4xq
```

Then `@a` to excute it again from the start of a different line.

You can also add `jF<` before the last q to automatically move the cursor to the next line.  Then you could chain the whole macro by doing 10@a.  Which would do the edit to 10 consecutive lines.

Comment: If you want more detail about the individual commands I did within the macro let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Vim golf: `qqf{yiB3T"Pldt"+q`

Comment: I didn't know about +, awesome

Answer (score 3):

You can use capture groups and `\zs`/`\ze` to make the substitution easy.

```
:%s/name="\zs[^"]*\ze" value="\${\([^}]*\)}/\1/
```

- `\zs` and `\ze` mark the start and end of the match that will be replaced
- `[^"]*` matches zero or more characters not matching `"`
- `\(...\)` a capture group. Represented in the replacement as `\1`, `\2`, ...

For more help see:

```
:h /\zs
:h /\(
:h /[
:h :s
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
:%s/name=".*" value="[$]{\(.*\)}"/name="\1" value="${\1}"/
```

Comment: Why are you capturing the value for `name`? You don't need that content.